# How to "sign anywhere"

Tags: signature

For a volunteer position at a local public institution, I have been given a list of policies to which I must agree. I have no issues with the specific policies.

My question is because I was asked to sign "anywhere" on the page and return the copy. I'm not sure it's wise to just "sign anywhere" without writing anything else around my name.

I'm considering writing "Acknowledged, (Signature)" but am not sure if there is a better legal phrase to be used in conjunction with my signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Acknowledged" is fine. There is no "preferable" substitute with which to prefix your signature.

As a precaution, never leave too much space between the end of clauses and your signature, lest another clause later on gets slid in without your consent (a public institution is unlikely to incur such misconduct, though). Also, always be sure to ask for a copy of the contract/agreement you sign.

Comment: In this case, I am returning the document electronically and will retain the original for my records. Thank you!